# PHP form vadation

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I am have created a form and having problems validating it as I am getting a few errors when I try to preview it in the browser.

**The errors**

```
Undefined index: username in  on line 269
Undefined index: email in  on line 270
Undefined index: fname in  on line 271
Undefined index: lname in  on line 272
Undefined index: pnumber in  on line 273
Undefined index: address in  on line 274
Undefined index: password in  on line 275

**my php scripts starts on line  35 and ends on line 131**
 <!--DB connection-->     (line 35)
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "student";
$dbpass = "student";
$dbname = "Curiosity_Pizza";

$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)or die ("Could not connect to database!");;
mysqli_select_db($connect, "$dbname" );
?>

<!-- inserting form data in to DB-->

<?php
$username =$_POST['username'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$fname =$_POST['fname'];
$lname =$_POST['lname'];
$pnumber =$_POST['pnumber'];
$address =$_POST['address'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);   

$inssert = 'INSERT into client(username, email, fname, lname, pnumber ,address,  password) VALUES ("'.$username.'","'.$email.'","'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'", "'.$pnumber.'", "'.$address.'","'.$password.'")';

mysqli_query($connect,$inssert);    
?>

<!--Registration Valadation-->
<?php

//define varibles and sst to empty (w3Schhols)
$usernameErr = $emailErr = $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $pnumberErr = $addressErr = $passwordErr = "";
$username = $email = $fname = $lname = $pnumber = $address = $password = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST"){
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    $email =  test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    $pnumber = test_input($_POST["pnumber"]);
    $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
    $password = test_input($_POST["passoerd"]); 
}

function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["userename"])){
        $usernameErr = "Userename is a required field";
    }else{
     $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])){
        $emailErr = "Email is a required field";
    }else{
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["fname"])){
        $fnameErr = "First Name is a required field";
    }else{
     $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lanme"])){
        $lnameErr = "Last Name is a required field";
    }else{
     $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["pnumber"])){
        $pnumberErr = "Phone Number is a required field";
    }else{
     $pnumber = test_input($_POST["$number"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["address"])){
        $addressErr = "Address is a required field";
    }else{
     $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["$password"])){
        $passwordErr = "Password is a required field";
    }else{
     $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    }
}   (line 131)

**My html/form not sure if its relevant low**
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" />
                                <table width="600" border="0">
                                  <tr>
                                    <th><label for="Username">Username:</label></th>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="username" />
                                    <span class="error">*<?php echo $usernameErr;?></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th><label for="email">email:</label></th>
                                    <td><input type="email" name="email" />
                                    <span class="error">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th><label for="fname">First Name:</label></th>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="fname" />
                                    <span class="error">*<?php echo $fnameErr;?></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th><label for="lname">Last Name:</label></th>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="lname" />
                                    <span class="error">*<?php echo $lnameErr;?></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th><label for="pnumber">Phone Number:</label></th>
                                    <td><input type="number" name="pnumber" />
                                    <span class="error">*<?php echo $pnumberErr;?></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th><label for="address">Address:</label></th>
                                    <td><input type="text"  name="address" />
                                    <span class="error">*<?php echo $addressErr;?></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th><label for="password">Passowrd:</label</th>                                   <td><input type="password"  name="password"   />
                                    <span class="error">*<?php echo       $passwordErr;?></span></td>
                                  </tr>                                                                         
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit"</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
```

I have tried reading the other posts on here but have not found anything that would work.

Comment: I don't know how I can have errors from line 269 -275 when my closing html tag is on line 257 (its a .php file)

Comment: Your `inserting form data in to DB` is REALY unsecure, totally expose to SQL injections!

Comment: @ Korri thanks but I was mid way through validating when I decide to test an found these errors so I just haven't gotten that far yet

Comment: if your "<!-- inserting form data in to DB-->" is executed before validation, then the setting of the $username and others below it will generate errors when the form is loaded 1st time, since the fields are empty. If you move DB section below validation and run it if the form is valid, than all should work.

Answer (score 1):

The errors means that the array does not contain the index. Make sure that your $_POST contains username... etc. Try

```
print_r($_POST)
```

And make sure it contains "username."

You can also use

```
array_key_exists("username", $_POST)
```

to make sure that $_POST contains username.

array_key_exists: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

**TL;DR**

Make sure $_POST contains "username" and any other index that PHP complains is undefined.

Comment: `in_array` doesn't work like that. You probably want [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead. Also, please reference php.net over w3schools when possible, the documentation is significantly better there.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the form that is posting information to make sure that the names match up with the parameters you're using.

For instance, you should have something like `<input name='username'>` somewhere in your form, etc.

Also, you should always do:

```
if( isset($_POST[INDEX]) )
{
    // Stuff with $_POST[INDEX]
}
```

to make sure that the POST was successfully received.

Also, you can try using Fiddler:

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

to figure out what is/isn't being posted.

Comment: Hay Brian thanks but I have checked an posted the html as part of my question/

Comment: Try using Fiddler to track the HTTP posts that happen.

Comment: Hi Brian sorry but am new to this what do you mean by fiddler

Comment: Fiddler is a tool to look at the HTTP GET and POST requests made when you access websites. I provided a link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$_POST['username']` as it might not contain username, first check if there is actually a value with [isset](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) `isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null`

or better, create a function to handle input data for example:

```
<?php
function post($index, $default = null) {
    return isset($_POST[$index]) ? $_POST[$index] : $default;
}

//Use it like that:
$username = post('username');
$email = post('email');
$fname= post('fname');
...
```

Edit: Added more example for better clarity.

Comment: Hay Korri please bear with me I am a beginner. So would I be correct in in saying that                                                                                                          <?php
function post($index, $default = null) {
    return isset($_POST[$index]) ? $_POST[$index] : $default;
}
                                                                                                       Checkes to if the user name has been entered if so would I need a new function for each index in the array or is there away of adding all the index's to the above function aging as I have said

Comment: (continuing from above comment)                                                                     <?php
function post($index, $default = null) {
    return isset($_POST[$username]) ? $_POST[$username]  && $_POST[$email]) ? $_POST[$email]  : $default;
}

Comment: @user2352979 It check is the key (`$index`) passed to it exists in the `$_POST` array. It it does, it returns the value, else it returns `$default`. You can use one function for all values.